# Reusing template for modal content causes "Type Error: Cannot redefine property: $nextTick"

Tags: javascript, jquery, alpine.js

I'm trying to integrate alpine.js into our custom CMS workflow.
One task is to render specific hidden elements, which are later used as content for a custom modal. My current setup is a template element with a data-modal tag:

```
        <template class="d-none bg-white" data-id="modal-02">
            <h1>Modal-02</h1>

            <div x-data="data_003" class="border" id="block_003">
                <div x-html="content">

                </div>
            </div>

        </template>
```

whichs content is later copied to the content of the modal, by the following code:

```
loadView(elementId, callback, forceReload = false) {
        // check if new elementId    
        if (elementId != this.elementId || forceReload) {

            // modal in template tag
            if ($("template[data-id='" + elementId + "'").length > 0){
                console.log("element found");
                this.emptyViewer();
                let tempElement = $("template[data-id='" + elementId + "'");
                var newElement = tempElement.html();

                // show element
                this.container.children(".xpe-modal-content").append(newElement);

                …
```

Before loading new content and after closing the modal I destroy the modals DOM with a jQuery empty() function:

```
    emptyViewer() {
        // search for old element in InfoViewer
        this.isEmpty = true;
        this.container.children(".xpe-modal-content").empty();
```

My current problem is, that only the first call to open the modal with the alpine code works, after closing it and opening it again i run into following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $nextTick

I assume this is related to not properly cleaning up the modals data, maybe some alpine-pros could help me on this.
You can find the entire code here: https://pwa.xpe.at/light-framework/structure_02.html
the button "lade modal 2" calls the modal with the alpine.js code.

As always, thanks for any heads up.

Comment: Where do you use `$nextTick`?

Comment: I don't use $nextTick myself, the problem is that with alpine.js 3.x you can't reuse the same x-data context (which happens here), see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69290431/how-to-reuse-alpinejs-data 
But I don't know a good workflow to avoid this issue (like manually destroying the x-data context after closing the modal.

Comment: Ok. Then my recommendation is to remove all jQuery code and use Alpine.js's data model. Could you share an example of `data_003` component and where do you call `loadView`?

Answer (score 1):

A `template` tag can only have a **singular** root element!
Most likely this is causing your issue.

P.S. You can reuse an `x-data` as many times without issue.

Example:

```html
<template class="d-none bg-white" data-id="modal-02">
    <div>
        <h1>Modal-02</h1>

        <div x-data="data_003" class="border" id="block_003">
            <div x-html="content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct with alpinejs 3.x. See this example, where the reuse of the x-data context causes the Error: Cannot redefine property: $nextTick
 
https://jsfiddle.net/Rechi/Lcep87as/8/

Comment: @WolfgangRechberger I've updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gqpc40ky/
You were not using `x-data` right. I've provided two ways of using `x-data`. The `Alpine.data` is most preferred since Alpine 3.

Comment: Thanks for the Info. This means that using already defined global js variables as x-data (without your proposed solutions) is the problem here? I thought that was the default way.

Comment: I've never been able to use variables for `x-data`. Always functions, until they updated to V3, in which I went with the then new and adviced `Alpine.data`. In both cases, it takes little change from the original however, and you also only need to define it once.